# UIbutton stretching after runtime

Tags: ios, constraints

I have form page with few textfields and a button.
I have added constraints for each component as well.

The issue is that the button getting stretched after running the app. 
Please see below screenshots for my issue.

**1- button size in storyboard**
[image: button size in storyboard]

**2- constraints**

[image]

**3- result in simulator**

[image]

Comment: Are you viewing on the same devices in both the storyboard and the simulator? It seems the simulator's height is bigger than in the storyboard, because you have a fixed space to the bottom of the view.

Comment: You need to remove bottom constrains to solve this issue. Please remove bottom constrains and try to run app.

Comment: Remove the bottom constraint and use a height constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of the device you implement your constraints in  is smaller than the device you test in , since you have leading , trailing , **top** and **bottom** your button will stretch depending on current device , so either remove the **top/bottom** constraint according to your design need

> You can **optionally** add height to the button or leave it with it's intrinsic size

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the height of the device you running is larger than the device you have selected on your storyboard. To overcome this issue.

- You can give a fixed height for the UIButton and remove the bottom layout constraint(lazy fix).
- The better and easiest way is to use vertical UIStackView and give proportional heights to all the components. Read this [article](https://www.journaldev.com/22059/ios-uistackview-stack-views) to gain more knowledge about UIStack views.